# Java Base b = new Derived(); inheritance questions

Tags: java, inheritance

What exactly happens when you create a new instance using :

```
Base b = new Derived();
```

I cannot really understand the mechanics behind this.

Comment: What exactly are you confused about? If you know the basics of Java, can you say more specifically what the problem with this declaration is?

Comment: This is a pretty fundamental concept in Java.  If you are having trouble with this, I thoroughly recommend finding yourself a good introductory Java book.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, from that point the compiler sees a `Base`instance and in runtime the instance is of type `Derived`.

In a broader explanation the `Base`type might be a interface, so you know by the contract what method has and what  it does `Polymorphism`. But you are abstracted from the  implementation.

Answer (score 5):

The reference to `b` is type `Base`. But the implementation is `Derived`. This means you can use it as a `Base` but it will behave as a `Derived`. Doing `b instanceof Derived` will be true because the implementation is of type `Derived`